# Variables that can be used in the whole symfony app? - Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, variables, global-variables, symfony4

So right now I'm developing an app in Symfony4 where the users can create files with one parameter that can be chosen between a variety of options (these options being already defined), for example:

```
Year = [2020,2019,2018,2017];
Type = ['A','B','C'];
User = [
  'User' => 'ROLE_USER',
  'Admin' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
  'Guest' => 'ROLE_GUEST',
];
```

And I would like that the admin could change this variables by adding a new year or adding a new type of file.
So I thought that this could be achievable by creating a global variable for the whole app (a variable that can be accessed from everywhere) in order to use it in the forms, views, etc. But I dont know how to do it.
I think I could do it in two ways:

- Creating a specific **table in the db** for these parameters, this way using doctrine to fetch the data and being able to updating it easily. (One more call to the database every time I want to use it)
- Or creating a **global variable** as I said before that I can access everytime I want

What should I do?
Is there any other easier way to achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I save these values in a table "settings" and use the cache so I don't have to make calls to the database every time I need to use them.

- Create entity Settings, it will have 3 properties : years, types, users. (they can be json type)
- I manually create 1 raw in the database and add the values, and the admin has a form to update these values
- I create a SettingCache class, and every time the admin submits the form, the values change, so I clear the cache : `$settingCache->clear()`.
- The next time I call `$settingCache->getSetting('years')` it will call the database to fetch the new values and rebuild the cache.

**App\Cache\SettingCache**

```
namespace App\Cache;

use App\Repository\SettingRepository;
use Psr\Cache\InvalidArgumentException;
use Symfony\Contracts\Cache\CacheInterface;

/*
 * Cache keys:
 *  - settings
 */
class SettingCache
{
    private $cache;
    private $settingRepository;

    public function __construct(
        CacheInterface $cache,
        SettingRepository $settingRepository
    ) {
        $this->cache = $cache;
        $this->settingRepository = $settingRepository;
    }

    public function getSettings(): array {
        return $this->cache->get('settings', function() {
            return $this->settingRepository->findAllToArray();
        });
    }

    public function getSetting(string $key) {
        $settings = $this->getSettings();
        return $settings[$key] ?? null;
    }

    public function clear(): void {
        $this->cache->delete('settings');
    }
}
```

**App\Repository\SettingRepository.php**

```
public function findAllToArray() {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->where('s.id = 1')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
}
```

That's it ! 
But because I also want to access these values in twig easily, I create a TwigFunction :
**App\Twig\SettingExtension**

```
namespace App\Twig;

use App\Cache\SettingCache;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class SettingExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    private $settingCache;

    public function __construct(SettingCache $settingCache) {
        $this->settingCache = $settingCache;
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('setting', [$this, 'getSetting']),
        ];
    }

    public function getSetting(string $key) {
        return $this->settingCache->getSetting($key);
    }
}
```

So I can call it in a template like

```
{% for year in setting('years') %}
    {{ year }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on the frequency that these variables will change. And the budget for the solution.

A database solution is very flexible but costs more time to create, migrate and maintain. It also would require a user interface to be able to update the variables.

The counterpart is a class Settings with a public static function that returns these variables. It is fast. It will require a programmer + deploy of the app any time these variables needs to be changed.